# reinstalling a module which don't rebuild the database

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1, installation

I installed a module which will build a table in database, then i manually drop that table, then i uninstall the module, after that, i reinstall the module but the table don't rebuild, how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing any module there is an entry for that module in the `core_resource` table.
Check the entry of your module there, delete the module entry from the table and then try to reinstall it again.